# Laravel check if ajax request not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I am using plain javascript for an ajax request like this:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'));
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'));
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.send(new FormData(form));
```

In Laravel controller I use the ajaxI() helper:

```
public function updateMenu(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->ajax());
}
```

It returns false, just like isXMLHttpRequest().,

What am I missing?

Comment: For it to be false, that means it's missing the `X-Requested-With` header, or it has the wrong value. Do you see the header being sent with the request in the network tab in your web inspector? What happens when you dump/log `$request->headers` in the controller?

Comment: @newUserName02 hehe I've added the header to the wrong ajax request, must've been too late. Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add headers to the right ajax request after drinking enough coffee

Answer (score -1):

you can use request method

> $method = $request->method();
>
> if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
>
> //code here
>
> }